# Is **kwargs in Python eager or lazy?

Tags: python, django, lazy-evaluation, keyword-argument

I'm trying to execute a Django query:

```
#att.name is a string
kwargs = {att.name : F('node__product__' + att.name) }
temps = Temp.objects.exclude(**kwargs)
```

I'm wondering if this is correct. All the examples I've seen so far use strings in the values,  but what if the value is a function, should I make the value a string, like this?

```
kwargs = {att.name : 'F('node__product__' + att.name)' }
```

Does the function in the value get executed eagerly in the argument list or does it wait until it's needed?

Comment: There is nothing lazy going on. The second form won't even parse.

Comment: is it reasonable to assume that you *meant* `kwargs = {att.name : "F('node__product__' + att.name)" }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python, expressions are always evaluated eagerly.  There is no lazy evaluation in python.  Some libraries get around the absence of this useful feature by allowing values that should be of some specific type to instead be a string, which it later `eval`s.  You can declare some parts of a django model this way (so that you can declare mutually referential foreign key relationships), but django's query interface does not.  You wouldn't normally be able to use this kind of technique when a string is "expected", because you'd have no way to distinguish string values from strings that should be `eval`ed.

Comment: You can pass lambda functions or functions object to simulate lazy evaluation. This is preferable than creating string that is eval-ed.

Comment: It may be preferable for reasons of "purity", but `"Foo.bar"` is enough more readable than `lambda: Foo.bar` and closer to the ideal `Foo.bar` that the string form is still common.  You can avoid the `eval` if you know what sort of strings to expect, and require a callable for anything clever.

Comment: There's an argument to be made that generators and generator expressions are evaluated "lazily".

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: not purity, but security. If you're dynamically building string for eval, you're susceptible for ensuring that the strings are safe, and does not contains stuffs like `'__import__("os").system("rm -rf /")'`.

Comment: No, you certainly don't want to `eval` anything that came from 'outside', but there's really not too much wrong with using strings in the specific context of the examples I've given.

Comment: @senderle: except, they are not.  They are not lazy expressions, rather they are basically similar concepts to functions definitions;  they aren't evaluated only if needed, they are evaluated exactly and precisely when you iterate over them.  This is a completely dual concept to function application, and nobody I know calls function bodies 'lazy'

Comment: "expression are evaluated eagerly, except never"? `foo() if condition else bar()`? `foo() or bar()`?

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative. I'm just pointing out that it's not uncommon to think of generators as lazy. For example, consider this line from wikipedia's [Python page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Generators): "generators are Python's mechanism for lazy evaluation of a function". More concretely, I don't know what to call [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) if not lazy; a strict version of `itertools.count` couldn't exist, in any sense of "strict" that I recognize.

Comment: @agf: still not a counterexample.  condition is evaluated every time.  That fully determines exactly if `foo()` gets evaluated or `bar()`, which proceeds immediately before the expression returns a value.  No additional computation is implied regardless of how the return value of the expression is used or not.  This is still eager evaluation, but there happens to be an explicit short circuit behavior in that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first one is correct:

```
kwargs = {att.name : F('node__product__' + att.name) }
temps = Temp.objects.exclude(**kwargs)
```

I don't understand how lazy/eager is related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments are evaluated before the function is called:

```
>>> def foo(x): return x
...: 

>>> foo(sum(range(10)))
<<< 45
```

When you create a dict everything is evaluated at that moment:

```
>>> kwargs = {'key': sum(range(10))}

>>> kwargs
<<< {'key': 45}
```

So...

```
>>> def foo(**kwargs): return kwargs
...: 

>>> foo(**kwargs)
<<< {'key': 45}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this question is because you are curious or if you are trying to find ways to load querys. So I will take a guess:

I would be using the Q() function and maybe load them on args to later use a for to set them on the Temp.objects.exclude, would be something like this:

```
def mylolfunc(self, *args,**kwargs):
    queryset = Q() 
    for query in args:
        queryset |= query
return Temp.objects.filter(queryset)
```

Where query is a Q(att.name = F('node_*product*_' + att.name)) or a lot more of Q objects.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) if you want to check it out.

This query will not execute until you ask for information, so it would be lazy. by that I mean until you do something like

```
myquery = mylolfunc(*args)
myquery[0]  #-----> executes query here
```